# Removing non alpha numeric characters from string and splitting strings words into a list to see if a condition has been met using regular expressions

Tags: python

[image: Issue]

I am completing a program that takes a sys argument(string) and checks if it's a palindrome or not.  My current code works if I have a single-word string.  However, I need to make sure the program would check each individual word and not factor in any non alphanumeric characters.  If any of the words are a palindrome then it would print it's a palindrome a single time.

Thought process:

My thoughts were to split each word into a list, have the list iterated to see if the condition has been met, and print only one time.  If I have multiple words it prints out it's not a palindrome.  Currently, it will just print it's not a palindrome multiple times if I provide a string with multiple words: ie 'racecar, racecar'

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is my code so far;

```
def palindrome():

    string = sys.argv[1].lower()
    remove_punc = string.strip('~`!@$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;<,>.?/')
    converted_string = remove_punc.split(' ')


    for i in converted_string:
        if converted_string == converted_string[::-1]:
            print('It\'s a palindrome!')
            break

        else:
            print('It\'s not a palindrome!')

palindrome()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Essentially I cannot figure out why my program won't iterate through the list, strip the nonalphanumeric characters, and check to see if its a palindrome.

Comment: Can you show an example of where your current code doesn't work?

Comment: Just added a picture of the output for a case in which I have multiple palindromes in a string seperated by the comma.  I am attempting to have my program use the strip() to remove the punctuation and then the split() to seperate each word from the blank space character.  After that I am attempting to have it loop through each word on the list to see if its a palindrome.  My issues are that I only would like to have it print its a palindrome once if there is any palindromes in the list.  The other issue is I dont think the split() is working when the for loop is supposed to iterate through it.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
import re

s = "aaa bbb, aaa"

s = re.sub("[^A-z]", "", s)

print(s == s[::-1])
```

### Update

With no regex:

```
s = "Al lets Della call Ed “Stella.”"

s = "".join([x for x in s.lower() if 123>ord(x)>96])

print(s == s[::-1])
```

To work with args:

```
s = sys.argv[1]

s = "".join([x for x in s.lower() if 123>ord(x)>96])

print(s == s[::-1])
```

[image]

### Update 2

If you want to check several palindromes at once, here you go:

```
import sys

for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    x = "".join([x for x in s.lower() if 123>ord(x)>96])
    print("'"+ s + "' is a palindrome? ", x == x[::-1])
```

[image]

Comment: I need to come up with the solution without having to import any libraries other than sys.  Thank you though!

Comment: I've updated my answer. It does the same -- removes all characters but [a-z] and compares the string with it inverted copy.

Comment: Awesome, this removes blank spaces?  I ask because if multiple words were entered then it would return false.

Comment: Just replace first line with `s = sys.argv[1]` and it will work with the arg

Comment: I’m not folllowing the logic on this if statement except for the last part of reversing the string.  Could you clarify what’s going on?

if 123>ord(x)>96])
    print("'"+ s + "' is a palindrome? ", x == x[::-1])

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_ord.asp. `ord("a")` = 96, `ord("z")` = 122. All letters from "a" to "z" should fall into the range `[96..122]`. `123>ord(x)>97` is the same as `[a-z]` in RegExp. `print` is just output the results (True or False) + some arbitrary text, you can output the results in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you!   I edited and did something similar to your answer that worked for me!  Code was posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter more than 1 word (thing with a space before or after),
you need to take all the arguments but the program itself, if your want to have each word. Then you clean them from non alpha chars, then you can test them.

```
import sys


def palindromes():

    words = sys.argv[1:]
    cleaned_words = [
        w.strip('~`!@$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;<,>.?/')
        for w in words
    ]
    for word in cleaned_words:
        if word == word[::-1]:
            print(f'{word} is a palindrome!')
        else:
            print(f'{word} is not a palindrome!')


palindromes()
```

Test:

```
$ python palindromes.py foo aba bar boob
foo is not a palindrome!
aba is a palindrome!
bar is not a palindrome!
boob is a palindrome!
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the submissions and this is the main part that worked for me.

```
    new_string = ''.join(i if i.isalpha() else '' for i in string)
    if new_string == new_string[::-1]:
        print('It\'s a palindrome!')
    else:
         print('It\'s not a palindrome!')
```

Comment: You don'n need `else`. The first line can be like this: `new_string = ''.join(i for i in string if i.isalpha())`